# finding solution to make variables equal in the below case

Tags: c#

```
var s1=new Student{ id=1,name="Sachin" }
var s2=new Student{ id=1,name="Sachin" }
```

The question is if `s1` is equal to `s2` then answer will be `false`, however what is the method to make `s1` equal to `s2`?

Comment: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, otherwise only references are compared:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get;  set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Student s2 = obj as Student;
        if (s2 == null) return false;
        return this.Equals(s2);
    }

    public bool Equals(Student s)
    {
        if (s == null) return false;
        return Id == s.Id && Name == s.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + Id;
            hash = hash * 23 + Name.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example two students are equal only if both, the id and the name are equal. Change it accordingly.

It is not really necessary to overload `Equals(Student)` and to override also `GetHashCode`. But it is strongly recommended. Read: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ID field is unique between all users, why not use that as your equality check?

```
if (s1.id == s2.id) {
   ...
}
```

It's usually best to start with the simplest solution before delving into the more [complicated way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you might find it's all you need.